# TASM Print 2D Array

Tags: assembly, tasm

TASM PRINT ARRAY

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    inventory db 10, 'Apples','Oranges','Potatoes','Tomatoes','Onions','Lemons','Milk','Eggs','Bread','Cheese',10,0
    quantity db 5, 3, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 10, 2, 7, 9
```

How do I code so that the data can output Number, Inventory and quantity like table... In TASM assembly language

For example:

[image]

Comment: You can do it the same way you would in C, printing each line left to right, with spaces or tabs.  You can count characters so you know how many spaces to print to get to the next column after printing something in this one.  Or in a DOS program you could use cursor-movement stuff to print down the columns as you iterate single arrays.

Comment: But note that you your `inventory` string is one flat string, equivalent to `db 'ApplesOrangesPotatoesTomatoesOnionsLemons...', 10, 0` because your list of operands for the `db` pseudo-instruction doesn't have anything between the strings.  Either put a special byte between them, like `db 10, 'Apples/Oranges/...'` or `db 10, 'Apples', 1, 'Oranges', 1, '...', 10, 0` or something.  Or make an array of pointers to strings, so it can be fixed-width.

Comment: That's not one 2d array, but two 1d arrays.

Comment: I wrote this. :) I put after each word from `inventory` array space character. So if space is detected program stops printing. I have code to print No and Quantity columns and after 2nd column's word is printed there is random space number so I calculated how many spaces insert before 3rd column.